# how to convert pyspark data frame columns into a dict

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with 2 columns.

```
Col1: String, Col2:String.
```

I want to create a dict like `{'col1':'col2'}`.

For example, the below csv data:

```
var1,InternalCampaignCode
var2,DownloadFileName
var3,ExternalCampaignCode
```

has to become :

```
{'var1':'InternalCampaignCode','var2':'DownloadFileName', ...}
```

The dataframe is having around 200 records.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
df_as_dict = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect())
```

---

Note that this is going to generate a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a single record of your pyspark dataframe:

```
[
  {'Col1': 'var1', 'Col2': 'InternalCampaignCode'},
  {'Col1': 'var2', 'Col2': 'DownloadFileName'},
  {'Col1': 'var3', 'Col3': 'ExternalCampaignCode'},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dict comprehension:

```
result = {r[0]: r[1] for r in df.collect()}
```

which gives

```
{'var1': 'InternalCampaignCode', 'var2': 'DownloadFileName', 'var3': 'ExternalCampaignCode'}
```